# How to set up a "Details" page when parsing from XML file in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, xml-serialization

I have an MVC VS2013 project querying an XML document.

The index action on my controller returns a list of Restaurants, and I need to be able to click the individual restaurants and open a details page which will show the respective properties of that Restaurant.

In previous projects querying from a sql database I would just call the db context, for example

> Restaurant restaurant = db.Restaurants.Find(id);

but I am uncertain what the XML querying equivalent is.

Here is what I have so far.

Model:

```
        [XmlRoot("EstablishmentCollection")]
        public class Restaurant
        {
        [Key]
        [XmlElement("FHRSID")]
        public int? FHRSID { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("BusinessName")]
        public string BusinessName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("RatingValue")]
        public int? RatingValue { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Hygiene")]
        public int? HygieneScore { get; set; }
 }
```

Controller:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    { 
        IQueryable<Restaurant> Res = null;

        try
        {
            var qy = xmlDoc.Descendants("EstablishmentDetail").Select(n => new  Restaurant()
            {
                FHRSID = (int)n.Element("FHRSID"),
                BusinessName = n.Element("BusinessName").Value,
                RatingValue = RValue(n),
                HygieneScore = HScores(n)
            });

            Res = qy.AsQueryable();
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string message;
            message = ex.Message.ToString();
            return View(message);
        }
        return View(Res);
       }


        public ActionResult Details (int? id)
       {
        try
        {
            var qy = xmlDoc.Descendants("EstablishmentDetail").Select(n => new Restaurant()
            {
                FHRSID = (int)n.Element("FHRSID"),
                BusinessName = n.Element("BusinessName").Value,
                RatingValue = RValue(n),
                HygieneScore = HScores(n)
             });

           //What goes here???

         }
         catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string message;
            message = ex.Message.ToString();
            return View(message);
        }




        return View();
    }
```

Details View:

```
 @model WebApplication3.Models.Restaurant


 <h2>Details</h2>
 <h6>@Model.FHRSID</h6>
 <h6>@Model.BusinessName</h6>
 <h6>@Model.HygieneScore</h6>
 <h6>@Model.RatingValue</h6>
```

EDIT:

I have been working on it, is something like the below heading in the right direction?
(Controller)

```
 public ActionResult Details (int? id)
    {
            var qy = xmlDoc.Descendants("EstablishmentDetail").Select(n => new Restaurant()
            {
                FHRSID = (int)n.Element("FHRSID"),
                BusinessName = n.Element("BusinessName").Value,
                RatingValue = RValue(n),
                HygieneScore = HScores(n)
            }).ToList();


            var query = from x in qy
                        where x.FHRSID == id
                        select new Restaurant();
            return View(query);
       }
```

Problem with the above is that I am having issues correctly sending the query to the view

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var r = xmlDoc.Descendants("EstablishmentDetail")
              .Select(n => new Restaurant()
              {
                  FHRSID = (int)n.Element("FHRSID"),
                  BusinessName = n.Element("BusinessName").Value,
                  RatingValue = RValue(n),
                  HygieneScore = HScores(n)
              })
              .Single(r => r.FHRSID == id);
```

`Single`, `SignleOrDefault`, `First`, `FirstOrDefault` returns an element from a collection.